# How to get exact value of choice field in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a choice field in Django model:

```
COMMITTEE_STATUS = (
    ("p", "Pending"),
    ("a", "Active"),
    ("c", "Completed"),
)
```

But the issue is when I am accessing these data in template I am getting p,a and c instead of actual pedning, active and complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because first value is actually stored in database, the other is just for humans. You have to do additional thing to get second value. According to [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) use this:

```
{{ yourobject.get_yourfield_display }}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
{{your_variable_name.get_fieldname_display}}
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.